# Which term describes fraudulently recording an asset more than once?

Tags: accounting, fraud

Imagine someone was working out how much my company was worth, and had tallied up the value of some machines that were in one of my factories, but then I move the machines to another factory (before she got there), so she would include the same machines twice in the valuation.

Is there a term that generally describes fraudulently causing an asset to appear to exist multiple times?

Note: I'm not thinking about doing this.

Comment: It's *not* "double-entry accounting". :P

Comment: Madoffing the books?

Answer (score 1):

Double counting. Typically just erroneous bookkeeping but sometimes done with fraudulent intent. In this case it results in overstating assets. I don't think there's a separate term for when double counting is done with intent to defraud.